# How should i know the phone that has the specified arguments is the hdpi or ldpi

Tags: android, android-layout, ps

As the titles,the following is some arguments of the psd of my phone:
The width pixels:
The height pixels:
The width of document is:13.333 inch
The height of document is :7.5 inch

so the dpi will be 96,and we will know the phone is just a ldpi phone as the http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
can anyone tell me whether it is right or not.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the pixels/inch screen density at run time?

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I know the pixels/inch screen density is 96,so i want to determine the abstract rosolution(ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xdpi) before i begin to devleop the software.For example,if know its abstract resolution is mdpi,so i will put the images that i crop in the drawable-mdpi folder of the application.

Comment: I don't know of any Android devices with a screen density of 96 pixels/inch. Do you mean the images were developed for a screen density of 96 and you want to know where to put them in your project's resource directory?

Answer (score 0):

If your graphics are designed to display at 96 pixels/inch, then they are not a good match for Android. The minimum density devices are nominally 120 pixels/inch (called LDPI). If you put your graphics in `res/drawable-ldpi`, they will appear about 96/120 (or about 3/4) their original size (in inches).

If the images are displayed on a higher density device, Android will automatically scale the images up, so they will keep this size ratio regardless of actual device pixel density.

The only way to fix this is to rescale your images before adding them to yuor project. You will get the best quality if you rescale to each of the nominal pixel densities (120, 160, 240, and 320; you could also throw in 213 for tvdpi screens).